# Spring JMS can not connect to WebSphere MQ - authentication fail

Tags: spring, security, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I config the WebSphere MQ with following command:

```
DEFINE QLOCAL(NEW.QL.RQ)
DEFINE QLOCAL(NEW.QL.RS)
DEFINE LISTENER('NEW.LSR') TRPTYPE(TCP) PORT(1420) CONTROL(QMGR) 
START LISTENER('NEW.LSR')
DEFINE CHANNEL('NEW.SVR.CONN') CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
SET CHLAUTH(*) TYPE(BLOCKUSER) USERLIST('nobody','*MQADMIN')
SET CHLAUTH(SYSTEM.ADMIN.*) TYPE(BLOCKUSER) USERLIST('nobody')
SET CHLAUTH(NEW.SVR.CONN) TYPE(ADDRESSMAP) ADDRESS(*) USERSRC(CHANNEL)
SET CHLAUTH(NEW.SVR.CONN) TYPE(BLOCKUSER) USERLIST('nobody')
REFRESH SECURITY
```

Then I can use MQ Explore connect to it successfully be using `mqm` username and empty password.

However, when I use spring jms, the authentication fail. The following section is my xml config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:main.properties" />

    <!-- WebSphere MQ Connection Factory -->
    <bean id="mqConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
        <property name="hostName">
            <value>${queue_hostname}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="port">
            <value>${queue_port}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="queueManager">
            <value>${queue_manager}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="transportType">
            <value>1</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="mqConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="username">
            <value>${mq.username}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${mq.password}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- JMS Destination Resolver -->
    <bean id="jmsDestinationResolver"
        class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver">
    </bean>

    <!-- JMS Queue Template -->
    <bean id="jmsQueueTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate102">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref bean="jmsConnectionFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="destinationResolver">
            <ref bean="jmsDestinationResolver" />
        </property>
        <property name="pubSubDomain">
            <value>false</value>
        </property>
        <property name="receiveTimeout">
            <value>20000</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageService" class="com.test.testspringjmsmq.MessageService" />
</beans>
```

The error messages:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'LOROL' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'xx.xx.xx.xx'. Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager you are connecting to
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:531)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:219)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:410)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7855)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7331)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:276)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6055)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopicConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection(MQTopicConnectionFactory.java:114)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQTopicConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQTopicConnectionFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:343)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.initConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:227)
at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:184)
at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:461)
... 25 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:206)
... 37 more
```

Comment: Check error log for the specific queue manager to see what userid your spring application is passing to queue manager. And check if that userid has authority to connect queue manager.

Comment: Thank you for your advise! I will check for that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I do not use Spring JMS to implement the connection between java and WebSphere MQ.

I directly use the simple JMS to implement it, and I think the configuration is more easy than Spring JMS.

The following section is the sample code for simple jms.

```
try {
      MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();

      // Config
      cf.setHostName("localhost");
      cf.setPort(1414);
      cf.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
      cf.setQueueManager("QM_thinkpad");
      cf.setChannel("SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN");

      MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection();
      MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///Q1");
      MQQueueSender sender =  (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);
      MQQueueReceiver receiver = (MQQueueReceiver) session.createReceiver(queue);      

      long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
      JMSTextMessage message = (JMSTextMessage) session.createTextMessage("SimplePTP "+ uniqueNumber);     

      // Start the connection
      connection.start();

      sender.send(message);
      System.out.println("Sent message:\\n" + message);

      JMSMessage receivedMessage = (JMSMessage) receiver.receive(10000);
      System.out.println("\\nReceived message:\\n" + receivedMessage);

      sender.close();
      receiver.close();
      session.close();
      connection.close();

      System.out.println("\\nSUCCESS\\n");
    }
    catch (JMSException jmsex) {
      System.out.println(jmsex);
      System.out.println("\\nFAILURE\\n");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println(ex);
      System.out.println("\\nFAILURE\\n");
    }
  }
```

Comment: I am trying to write some samples using Spring framework and I am facing the same problem as you. What I see is JmsAccessor class in Spring framework does not have a createConnection method that takes userId and Password. Hence client connection to queue manager fail.